# AFNetworking batch requests - canceling when first one fails

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking code for batching requests. I have really copy & paste from example code - it looks like that:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableOperations = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSURL *fileURL in filesToUpload) {
    NSURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"http://example.com/upload" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData
        [formData appendPartWithFileURL:fileURL name:@"images[]" error:nil];
    }];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    [mutableOperations addObject:operation];
}

NSArray *operations = [AFURLConnectionOperation batchOfRequestOperations:mutableOperation progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {
    NSLog(@"%lu of %lu complete", numberOfFinishedOperations, totalNumberOfOperations);
} completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
    NSLog(@"All operations in batch complete");
}];

[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperations:operations waitUntilFinished:NO];
```

Now what I want to achieve is to cancel all other operation in that queue if the first one fails.

I found a solution for 1.0.3 with AFHttpClient but nothing for 2.0.

Any tips ?

Comment: As an aside, is it really critical to download all of the images in advance? For many user interfaces, it's much better to employ lazy loading (e.g. via AFNetworking's `UIImageView` category). Clearly, if you must download all of them, do so, but if it's possible that the user might not need _all_ of them, just download them as you need them. If you download all, you might unnecessarily consume the user's battery, data plan, network bandwidth, etc.

Comment: I'm doing something else than downloading images. I'm uploading some JSON data but for simplification I used example from AFNetworking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than adding the operations to the `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]`, create your own operation queue. So, in your `@interface` define a queue:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSOperationQueue *networkQueue;
```

Then, instantiate a queue:

```
self.networkQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
self.networkQueue.name = @"com.domain.app.networkqueue";

// if you want it to be a serial queue, set maxConcurrentOperationCount to 1
//
// self.networkQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
// 
// if you want it to be a concurrent queue, set it to some reasonable value
//
// self.networkQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 4;
```

Then, add your network operations to this queue (bypassing `batchOfRequestOperations`):

```
NSOperation *completionOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"All operations done");
}];

// NSOperation *previousOperation = nil;   // if you uncomment dependency code below, uncomment this, too

for (NSURL *fileURL in filesToUpload) {
    NSURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"http://example.com/upload" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData
        [formData appendPartWithFileURL:fileURL name:@"images[]" error:nil];
    }];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    // if you want the operations to run serially, you can also
    // make each dependent upon the prior one, as well
    //    
    // if (previousOperation)
    //     [operation addDependency:previousOperation];
    //
    // previousOperation = operation;

    [completionOperation addDependency:operation];

    [self.networkQueue addOperation:operation];
}

[self.networkQueue addOperation:completionOperation];
```

And, finally, if you want to cancel the operations, you can do:

```
[self.networkQueue cancelAllOperations];
```

Comment: Don't forget to make the second operation dependent on the first. Otherwise you may find the second operation is actually run before the first one!

Comment: @DavidCaunt They get dependency from AFNetworking. I will try that solution.

Comment: If you're using [AFURLConnectionOperation batchOfRequestOperations:], yes, you're right.

Comment: @DavidCaunt Agreed, if the order is important, make sure to set dependencies. But if downloading a bunch of images, it's much better to (a) use the concurrent queue; and (b) make sure that your code is not dependent upon the order (e.g. have the completion block update the model based upon the index of the image). You pay serious performance penalty if doing serial network requests. Much faster to do them concurrently and just make sure the completion blocks are not assuming that they'll be downloaded in order.

Comment: I completely agree. I read the OP's question to have the requirement that the second request should not be made if the first one fails. If that's not the case then uploading in parallel should perform much better.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it's not working. Anyways it's processing other requests even first one failed :( If you take a look at batchOfRequestOperations implemnetation in AFNetworking it adds all of them to dispatch_group_async - maybe that's the reason.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski You can enqueue the operations yourself without using batchOfRequestOperations. In this way, you can make a serial queue as Rob suggested and configure the dependencies yourself.

Comment: Yeah probably I will write my own network management code which will be fitting my requirements. Thanks for advices.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski Very good. Because you're using `NSOperation`-based framework, this should be very easy. Anyway, I expanded my answer to illustrated David's point. But definitely use `NSOperationQueue` rather than GCD-based solution, because that makes it much easier to cancel queue network operations.